# Populating grid date from based on timestamps

Tags: sql, join, gridview, google-bigquery

I have two following tables that I want to join:

```
 select 
    user_id
    , date 
 from users 
 where id = 13 
 order by date descending
```

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 2020-06-31 |
| 13 | 2020-06-30 |
| 13 | 2020-06-29 |
| 13 | 2020-06-28 |
| 13 | 2020-06-27 |
| 13 | 2020-06-26 |

```
select 
   user_id
   , date
   , orders_count_sum 
from orders 
where user_id = 13 
order by date descending
```

| user_id | date | orders_count_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2020-06-30 | 3 |
| 13 | 2020-06-27 | 2 |
| 13 | 2020-06-26 | 1 |

I want to join the orders table to users, so that I get **orders_count_sum** populated over dates:

| userid | date | orders_count_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2020-06-31 | 3 |
| 13 | 2020-06-30 | 3 |
| 13 | 2020-06-29 | 2 |
| 13 | 2020-06-28 | 2 |
| 13 | 2020-06-27 | 2 |
| 13 | 2020-06-26 | 1 |

Doing a left join here will only show order_count_sum for the dates from the second table. How can I populate the users tabls grid date with latest for that date  **orders_count_sum**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `lead()` and then `join`

```
select u.user_id, u.date, o.orders_count_sum
 from users u join
      (select o.*,
              lead(date) over (partition by o.user_id order by date) as next_date
       from orders o
      ) o
      on o.user_id = u.user_id and
         u.date >= o.date and
         (u.date < o.next_date or o.next_date is null);
```

You can filter down to a particular user if you also want that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select user_id, date, 
  last_value(orders_count_sum ignore nulls) over win orders_count_sum
from users u 
left join orders o 
using (user_id, date)
window win as (partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you might noticed - in your sample data I changed MONTH from `06` to `05` as there is no such a date as `JUNE 31` unless you are in the word of Priestley's fantasy Book

[image]